# Rename file name with Regex and get rid of everything after with powershell

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

Hi I'm trying to rename file names with regex and powershell. I got it to replace certain files with the following code but i want to do this for everything after the _underscore. I got over a hundred files i need to rename.

`get-childitem *.pdf | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_R12B", "") }`

Here are example files i'm trying to change;

YTER-01-0B-B-PD-00003-2_R12B

YTER-01-0A-B-PZ-00001-2_R9B

YTER-01-0U-B-PG-00003-1_R1B

YTER-01-0G-B-PP-00005-1_R4B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
get-childitem *.pdf | foreach { rename-item $_ ($_.Name -replace '_[^_]+(?=\.pdf$)') }
```

The `_[^_]+(?=\.pdf$)` regex matches

- `_` - an underscore
- `[^_]+` - 1+ chars other than an underscore
- `(?=\.pdf$)` - followed with `.pdf` at the end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bo3LlX/1).